# Using process modelling library for vessel sailing behavior in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I want to use 'process modelling library' to mimic vessel movement from one point to another (because 'road traffic library' cannot realistically reflect the ship movement).

However, I am stuck at defining a way for speed control and keeping a safe distance between two vessels. What I want to achieve is the speed of each vessel (agent) should be restricted in a threshold [MaxSpeed,MinSpeed], and all the vessels should keep a safe distance/time with the vessels in front or behind. For example, if a vessel with speed 15 knots catches the vessel with speed 10 knots, it will change the speed to 10 knots before reaching the required safe distance/time.

Currently, what I am thinking is to set the agent speed at 'Source' block or 'MoveTo' block, and create a function to avoid collision. Does anybody know how the function will look like? I am very appreciate if any idea or comments, thanks!

Comment: probably more elegant and easier to use a pure agent approach with state charts. Internal state transitions could constantly check distance to other ships while moving, and adjusting speed. However, in any case, this will be a fair bit of manual coding as there is no functionality for this by default.

Comment: Yes, I found that Anylogic doesn't provide too much detail on ship transportation. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though depending on your model there may be smart ways of doing this, I will show you a generic inefficient way of doing this in a very simplified way without deceleration or any fancy stuff.

It's a good idea to first set up a node in front of your boat as a safety distance:
[image: boat with safety distance]

I also added an event that will check if other boats are getting too close to the boat itself... so in the event you can have code like this that runs every minute for example:

```
for(Boat c : main.boats){   
    if(unsafeDistance.contains(c.getX()-getX(),c.getY()-getY())){
        setSpeed(c.getSpeed());
        break;
    }
}
```

This code checks if there is any boat inside the safety node, and if there is one, the boat will instantaneously change its speed to the speed of the boat in front of it.

This code is ugly and inefficient, but if you want something better, you need to think about it yourself using the characteristics of your situation in order to make it better... but this solution should work using moveTo blocks from the Process modeling library.

Comment: It looks like a nice way to transfer a complicated problem into simplified manner, I am very appreciate your idea!